# Laravel 5 - Load all templates in a folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to read all the templates that are inside a folder, but searching in documentation and in the API I can't found nothing that helps me.

Also I want to read only the section `info` of each template. Any idea?

Comment: Why you are reading all templates ? Instead make a common template and then display the `info` or whatever you want whenever the view is called

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen CMS purposes, each template has an info that I need to load in Controller.

Comment: You mean, you want to load the view with some dynamic values in it ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen Yes, in the template I'll have some data, and I want to Iterate over all templates inside a folder, read that data, and create a drop-down menú in the admin panel with this info

Comment: I wrote an answer for you. If you need more help. reply in my answer

Comment: use _view composers_ for this, not a _template_

Comment: @itachi any clue about how to do that?

Comment: i dont think Laravel view is capable of doing what you are looking for. You will need to write your own view class. 
in that do a scandir  and read the template files your self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a php function to [scan the directories](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) and build an array of the text files you want to look into - and build arrays keyed by filepaths that contain the strings you want to use.

Comment: It's the more approach. I solved it using Finder() to scan the directories and then using a regex to extract text between closures to parse it

Comment: Okay - sounds like you are doing something pretty similar, yours is better as it uses a Symfony component which is more Laravel like - so more maintainable.  I found this link to Finder which I found useful: http://keltdockins.com/2014/09/09/searching-files-with-laravel/

Comment: the above keltdockins.com link is now dead. It can be found though via archive.org
http://web.archive.org/web/20150215042715/http://keltdockins.com/2014/09/09/searching-files-with-laravel/

Answer (score 0):

To display the dynamic values inside your view

This is will be your controller

```
$data= 'This is the value';
return View::make('home')->with('data', $data);
```

In your views you should have the file `home.blade.php` and you shall echo the `$data` by `{{ $data }}` or `echo $data` inside your view

Comment: Sorry I think there's a confussion here. I already know how to use views, and extends it, and creates @sections and after @yield the content. I also knows how to pass data to the view. What I want is a way to loop over all views inside a folder (dinamically) and retrieve only one section from them. All of this inside Controller. Then, with that info, I could do thing in my `PageController@createPage` method

Comment: I am not clear, You mean you want to do `foreach` inside the view and display all the menu or display one record to the view from Controller ?

Comment: I want to make something like ` $views = View::loadByFolder('pages');` and get an array with all the views inside the folder `pages`. Then a `foreach($views as $view) { $template_info = $view->getSection('info') }`. And that's all, do something with that $template_info

Comment: You want to display all the blades that are inside the folder as a menu ?

Comment: Yes, but processing the @section('info') first in the Controller

Comment: then you should `scandir` and get the name in the controller. You want me to assist in this ?